# find command is not working properly

Tags: find

When I run the command `find -L /home/yabir/Descargas/ -mtime 0 -mtime -12` to find for the files that have been modified 12 days before today in the Descargas folder I get nothing. I have this folder with some files and when I click on properties It says that the last modification was 3 days ago. Then when I modify a text file in the folder, It appears in the search. Is it a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give two tests, this implies AND condition. You are asking for files that were modified less then 12 days ago AND today. Then you get what you asked.